# How to upload image/file using custom customer attribute with Rest API Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, customer-attribute, file-upload, store-front

I have create one custom customer attribute with file type. I want to upload file using rest API and want to store it to custom media path.

How to upload file is with customer registration API?

Comment: It's done? if yes please share the answer in a comment.

Comment: I am also searching its simply not possible in M2 APIs

Comment: does anyone have a solution for this?